# React Native Signed APK secure credentials

Tags: react-native, android-keystore

I am going to generate my APK to upload to the play store. I am following the React-Native [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android).

I want to protect my keystore password. But I use Windows (in the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android#setting-up-gradle-variables) it only appears for OSX)

I try `storePassword Console.ReadLine("\n\$ Enter keystore password: ")` but didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Generate the APK from Android Studio. I Follow the steps in this [tutorial](https://www.instamobile.io/android-development/generate-react-native-release-build-android)

Remember choose "Generate Signed Bundle / APK" on Android Studio